# Is there a way to verify if a livestreamed image is available to load before displaying it?

Tags: javascript, html, http-live-streaming

I made a very simple project a while ago that consists of two videos (that come from a security camera array which is livestreamed) that are randomly chosen and displayed for 1 minute only. After 1 minute is up, the page's refreshed and a new set of two videos show up. But the problem is: some security cameras aren't available all the time because of server issues, so once in a while what happens is that 2 videos are randomized and one (or both of them) aren't displayed, so I was wondering is there a way to code this?

For some reason I was only able to code the array of security cameras as images, not as videos.

Here's the code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var myPix = new Array("http://180.23.155.164:8082/-wvhttp-01-/GetOneShot?&frame_count=1000000000#.XuE-YLJZhYI.link",
      "http://180.220.70.194:1024/-wvhttp-01-/GetOneShot?&frame_count=1000000000#.XujHZZ-5jOU.link",
      "http://107.85.194.33:8081/-wvhttp-01-/GetOneShot?&frame_count=1000000000#.XujTCpm4q4M.link");
    //the list is very long so i'll stop here
    function choosePic() {
      var randomNum = Math.round(Math.random() * myPix.length);
      var randomNum2;
      // Keep generating randomNum2 if randomNum equals randomNum2
      do {
        randomNum2 = Math.round(Math.random() * myPix.length)
      } while (randomNum === randomNum2);
      document.getElementById("myPicture").src = myPix[randomNum];
      document.getElementById("myPicture2").src = myPix[randomNum2];
    }
    // First loading of camera resources
    choosePic();
  )
};
```

```html
<section class="hero is-fullheight has-background-black">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container">
      <figure class="center">
        <img width="512px" height="384px" id="myPicture">
        <img width="512px" height="384px" id="myPicture2">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I'm coder beginner, so I don't know if this is something silly which I'm foreseeing or not.

Comment: When the pictures are not made well, what does it show? an image that's all black?

Comment: It shows a little square with an image icon

Comment: You can try to get the image's size, and recognize a pattern. For example, you may realize that dead images have a size under 10kb and automatically re-take a snapshot

Comment: How would I get the image's size if it doesn't open? I'm not sure if it's possible either because they're all live streamed from their ips, when it's not available it merely means that the livestream from that specific camera is down (because of bad network connection or lack of power) but it may get online again after a while